# Tap Image, remove labels, show image only

Tags: ios

This is a sort of multi-part question, I don't think I need the code, but I do need the approach.  I am using storyboards and have a screen that has a dynamically shown image with some labels and descriptive text.  I want to add functionality such that when the user taps the image, all the text and labels 'disappear' and just the image is shown, taking up the full screen.  The image should be zoomable.  When the user taps the image it should bring them back to the 'image with text' view.
Thanks for any help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

My approach:
On click on image, create a new viewcontroller with big image and with animation of alpha and scale. Viewcontroller have a zoom feature. When tap, remove the viewcontroller after animating back of alpha and scale.

Comment: Another view controller - thanks.  How do I recognize the 'tap' on the image?

Comment: add a tap gesture on the image ??!!